# How do I move the legend position in a pie chart into the pie?

Tags: charts, microsoft-excel-2016

I am using Excel 2016 and I cannot figure out how to move the "Legend Position" to be inside of the Pie chart.

I have done this in older versions. How do I do it in 2016?

Answer (score 3):

You can drag the legend into the pie. In the Format Legend dialog untick the box to "Show the legend without overlapping the chart", then drag it where you need it.

[image]

Or do you mean adding data labels to the pie slices, so the series name or the value (or both), or some other text can show inside the pie slices?

To achieve that, click the Plus button next to the chart and add data labels. Use the options in data label formatting dialog to select what the label should show.

And, just as a reminder: if your pie has more than three slices, you're using the wrong chart type. Use a horizontal bar chart instead.

[image]

Comment: Thank you, +1. Took me way too long to find this easy solution

Comment: perfect answer, good job

Answer (score 0):

- Click on your chart
- Click on button "Chart styles"
- Now you can select the style you want. Many styles are actually is
  what you want

Where to click and how it'll look:
[image: See where to click and how it'll look]